# mouse_event координаты не соответствуют реальным

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу

```
 mouse_event((0x0001), 0, 1000, 0, 0);
```

Но мышь перемещается вниз не на 1000 пикселей,а на 500,почему?

Comment: А что за пороговое значение?И как тогда написать чтоб перемещало на расстояние, которое я написал?

Comment: Честно говоря я не понял о чем эта ссылка и как мне использовать ту функцию в целях перемещения мыши.И как мне узнать какое у меня пороговое значение мыши